# Ace text editor - "require" fails if the source is minified

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ace-editor

I am attempting to use the `ace` text editor with `angular`, and one of the needed behaviors requires a call to `ace.require`.

I've included the appropriate files, but I am seeing that if I minify my javascript source, that doesn't work anymore. This is clearly because the path becomes invalid, but I'm not sure how to handle the situation except to manually load the mentioned files outside of my optimized bundles. I am using `ASP.NET MVC Web Optimization Framework` to load my javascripts as "bundles" that are compact and minified.

I am using **[ui-ace](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-ace)** directive to load it, but I have tested without any directive and the behavior is the same whether or not I am going through angular.

Has anyone else discovered a workaround to this?

It's pretty simple code ...

## Bundle

```
bundles.Add( new ScriptBundle( "~/bundles/js/ace" )
    // include the ace text editor
    .Include( "~/application/assets/scripts/ace/ace.js" )
    .Include( "~/application/assets/scripts/ace/ext-language_tools.js" )));
```

## Javascript

```
    if (angular.isDefined(opts.require)) {
        opts.require.forEach(function (n) {
            window.ace.require(n);
        });
    }
```

This can also just be typed explicitly as ...

```
ace.require('ace/ext/language_tools');
```

## HTML

```
<div ng-model="Model.Scripting"
     ui-ace="{
        useWrapMode: true,
        showGutter: true,
        theme: 'chrome',
        mode: 'javascript',
        require: ['ace/ext/language_tools'],
        advanced: {
            enableSnippets: true,
            enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
            enableLiveAutocompletion: true
        }
    }">
</div>
```

## HOW TO REPRODUCE

Since I cannot figure out a way to get the whole thing to you exactly as it needs to be, I've recreated the behavior using `nodejs`, `bower`, and `gulp`.

## NODE JS/BOWER

Start by running these commands in nodejs, in a new folder.

`npm install bower`
`npm install gulp`
`npm install gulp-concat`
`npm install gulp-rename`
`npm install gulp-uglify`
`npm install run-sequence`

`bower install angular`
`bower install ace-builds`
`bower install angular-ui-ace`

## GULP

You can use this `gulpfile.js` to build the script file.

```
var
  gulp = require('gulp'),
  concat = require('gulp-concat'),
  rename = require('gulp-rename'),
  uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
  sequence = require('run-sequence');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  return sequence([
    "ace"
  ]);
});

gulp.task('ace', function() {
  return gulp.src([
    'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
    'bower_components/angular-ui-ace/ui-ace.js',

    'bower_components/ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace.js',
    'bower_components/ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-javascript.js',
    'bower_components/ace-builds/src-noconflict/worker-javascript.js',
    'bower_components/ace-builds/src-noconflict/theme-chrome.js',
    'bower_components/ace-builds/src-noconflict/snippets/text.js',
    'bower_components/ace-builds/src-noconflict/snippets/javascript.js'])
    .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('js'));
});
```

## INDEX.HTML

This is an HTML file that can reproduce the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            var ace = window.ace = window.ace || { };
            ace.initialize = function(editor) {
                ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools");

                editor.setTheme("ace/theme/chrome");
                editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");

                // options
                editor.setOptions({
                    showGutter: true,
                    showPrintMargin: false,
                    enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
                    enableSnippets: true,
                    enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
                    fontSize: '14px',
                    fontFamily: 'Consolas'
                });
            };
        })();
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('app', ['ui.ace'])
                .controller('HomeController',['$scope', function($scope){
                    $scope.aceLoaded = function(_editor){
                        ace.initialize(_editor);
                    };

                    $scope.Model = {
                        Scripting: ""
                    }
                }]);
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="HomeController">
    <div ui-ace="{ onLoad: aceLoaded }"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you setup a fiddle?

Comment: I will try to get you something here momentarily. I think I figured out a way to get you a sample.

Comment: Alright. I've provided the instructions for easily re-creating the entire thing. Is that useful at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For ace.require to work you need to add ext-language_tools to your `gulp.task("ace")`

```
'bower_components/ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace.js',
'bower_components/ace-builds/src-noconflict/ext-language_tools.js',
'bower_components/ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-javascript.js',
```

`bower_components/ace-builds/src-noconflict/worker-javascript.js` isn't needed in the bundle since it needs to be loaded in the webworker. For that to work you need to configure workerPath to point to the right folder

```
ace.initialize = function(editor) {
    ace.require("ace/config").set("workerPath",
        "bower_components/ace-builds/src-min-noconflict");
    ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools");
```

and for ace not being visible initially because of it's height being set to 0 see this question: [Ace editor doesn't work with bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821470/ace-editor-doesnt-work-with-bootstrap/25830964#25830964)

also note that `fontFamily: 'Consolas'` might cause problems on systems where that font is missing, so it's better to add a fallback to monospace like `fontFamily: 'Consolas', monospace`

Comment: I had a different problem.. require was not working (noconflict) So I did this:  ```ace.config.set("workerPath",  "worker");```  where worker is the path of my workers.. If you minified your project; do not forget to make them available in that path

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to my answer on github (lahdo) if above solution is not working for you (workers are still not loaded properly):

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-ace/issues/106

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).